# Putting HTML tags that are CSS grid layout children into a <section> tag to be more WCAG friendly

Tags: html, css, wcag

Using CSS Grid for the layout of a webpage, is it possible to make a semantic grouping of tags within tags such as `<section>` without breaking the grid layout when items inside that semantic grouping are meant to be direct children of the grid container?

I would like to do this semantic grouping to force myself to conform to WCAG norms by grouping content into coherent units (https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_section_element); the problem that I'm facing is that I can't see how I could group the header into a `<section>` while maintaining my layout, which consists partly of a grid cell dedicated to the logo.

HTML markup

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
    <!-- I tried to put a <main> tag instead of a div here, but as a result I
         got a blank page showing nothing else but the logo top left 
         of the page -->       
    <div id="wrapper">

      <!-- header, semantic grouping #1 that I would like to make -->
      <div id="logo" ><img src="../assets/images/some_image.png"/></div>
      <div id="header"><h1>header h1</h1></div>

      <!-- content, semantic grouping #2 that I would like to make -->
      <div id="left_aside">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div id="right_content">test right content</div>

      <!-- footer, semantic grouping #3 that I would like to make -->
      <footer>test footer</footer>

    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper -->

  </body>
```

CSS style

```css
/* whole */
body {
    margin  : 0;
    height  : 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    height               : 100vh;
    width                : 100vw;
    display              : grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr;
    grid-template-rows   : 2fr 17fr 1fr;
    grid-gap             : 2px 2px;
}

/* header */
#logo {
    grid-column    : 1/2;
    grid-row       : 1/2;
    display        : flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
    padding        : 1em;
}
img {
    max-width  : 150px;
    max-height : 90px;
}
#header {
    grid-column    : 2/4;
    grid-row       : 1/2;
    display        : flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
}
h1 {
    text-align    : center;
}

/* content */
#left_aside { 
    background : yellow;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row   : 2/3;
}
#right_content { 
    background : black;
    color      : white;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row   : 2/3;
}

/* footer */
footer { 
    background : orange;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row   : 3/4;
}
```

I must say I'm pretty confused here since most recommendations basically say that favoring grid over semantic grouping is something to avoid:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_Layout_and_Accessibility

> to use a set of `<div>` elements instead as then you can have the element to be a direct child of a container set to `display: grid`. Be aware of this temptation and find ways to develop your design without stripping out the markup. Starting out with a well-structured document is a very good way to avoid the problem, as you will be aware that you are removing semantic elements in order to make the layout work if you actually have to go into the document and do so!

I'm afraid I didnt find the right structure or examples yet to address my problem.

Comment: That Mozilla quote is basically saying HTML `<elements>` are semantic. The layout doesn't change HTML that started out semantic. But you might be tempted to remove some semantic elements to achieve the layout you want.

Comment: indeed, but is there any work-around or technique to reconciliate semantic and visual grouping ? I'm asking because I have no clue ^^

Comment: I *think* the point is that anything that cares about semantic HTML doesn't know anything about what CSS does to the visual layout. So its more important that your logo is referenced as an `h1` or `<picture>` than if it visually sits beside or above the content. At least that's my interpretation. In your case, I'd recommend using semantic HTML5 tags instead of divs. `<section>`, `<aside>`, etc

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense; we could say that the meaning of the tag is probably more important than its location inside the markup... then again, people specialized in linguistics would say that the context of an expression is as much (if not more) important than it's actual meaning

Comment: Right, context matters, even in HTML but you can always use CSS to move things visually while they stay in their semantic context and a "robot" parser that only looks at HTML is none the wiser...

Comment: haha, well said; thank you for giving me food for thought ! I will definitely look more into the UX of screen-readers to answer to apprehend these questions better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does assigning the added grouping elements `display:contents` get what you need? Like this:

```css
/* whole */
body {
    margin  : 0;
    height  : 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    height               : 100vh;
    width                : 100vw;
    display              : grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr;
    grid-template-rows   : 2fr 17fr 1fr;
    grid-gap             : 2px 2px;
}

section {
  display:contents;
}

/* header */
#logo {
    grid-column    : 1/2;
    grid-row       : 1/2;
    display        : flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
    padding        : 1em;
}
img {
    max-width  : 150px;
    max-height : 90px;
}
#header {
    grid-column    : 2/4;
    grid-row       : 1/2;
    display        : flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
}
h1 {
    text-align    : center;
}

/* content */
#left_aside { 
    background : yellow;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row   : 2/3;
}
#right_content { 
    background : black;
    color      : white;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row   : 2/3;
}

/* footer */
footer { 
    background : orange;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row   : 3/4;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
    <!-- I tried to put a <main> tag instead of a div here, but as a result I
         got a blank page showing nothing else but the logo top left 
         of the page -->       
    <div id="wrapper">

     
      <!-- header, semantic grouping #1 that I would like to make -->
      <section>
        <div id="logo" ><img src="../assets/images/some_image.png"/></div>
        <div id="header"><h1>header h1</h1></div>
      </section>

      <!-- content, semantic grouping #2 that I would like to make -->
      <section>
        <div id="left_aside">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="right_content">test right content</div>
      </section>
      <!-- footer, semantic grouping #3 that I would like to make -->
      <footer>test footer</footer>

    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper -->
```

Comment: I assigned a section to each of the groupings and applied `display:contents` to them it worked ! this is brilliant, thanks Alohci !

Answer (score 4):

Building on what @Alochi said and on our discussion in the comments, I'd change the HTML tags you're using to be more semantic. You can then "hide" the semantic containers as needed with CSS `display: contents` to achieve the layout you want.

```html
      <!-- content, semantic grouping #2 that I would like to make -->
      <!-- use markup tags to show intent aside, nav, section, article -->
      <article>
        <aside id="left_aside">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </aside>
        <section id="right_content">test right content</section>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper -->
```

Here's an [overview](https://www.semrush.com/blog/semantic-html5-guide/) of "semantic" markup using HTML5 tags. And a [good description](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/01/29/vanishing-boxes-with-display-contents/) of what `display: contents` is doing from Rachel Andrew.